# factors that are important for success when letting an agile framework emerge for the whole organisation?

Tags: agile

I previously posted a question [[link]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/244623/when-to-use-a-scaled-enterprise-agile-software-development-framework-and-when-to) on programmers.stackexchange.com asking when it makes sense to adopt an existing enterprise scale agile framework and when it makes sense to allow your own enterprise scale agile framework to emerge (e.g. through trial and error).

This question takes the previous question a step further and asks for **the factors that are important for success** when you have decided to go down the route of letting your enterprise scale agile framework emerge?

--
Downvoters: down voting without adding a comment provides no opportunity for improving the question.  Please let me know why you are down voting so that I can improve the question.

Comment: I think this is a question that really can only be answered in a post mortem...

Comment: @closers - I believe the comprehensiveness and conciseness of the [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/245163/80059) shows that the question is not too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When discussing the question above with practitioners from the scaledagile.com, the following questions were raised:

- Are we achieving the business results with our existing processes?
- Is the business satisfied with our time to market?
- Do we have the
  time, resources and skills to document the emerging process?  If we
  don’t document the new processes, how will this knowledge be
  institutionalized?
- How long is the company willing to wait for the
  scaling agile practices to emerge?
- What is the cost of the delay?
- How slow do we want to wait for this process to emerge?
- Do we have a
  track record of scaling?
- Do we truly understand lean and agile
  practices? If we don’t, how will we know what and how to improve?
- Do
  our teams have a track record of continuous improvement.  If yes, why
  haven’t the teams already developed these scaling practices already? 
  If no, what will change to enable this new scaling process to emerge?
- Are the teams empowered to make process changes, re-org teams and
  create new roles.
- Do the teams have a holistic view of the
  organization, and have the mindset to look at the big picture and
  make process changes that do not cause local optimization at the
  expense of the whole.
- Will the teams be limited due to their
  thinking “We can’t change that, they won’t allow us to”, “we’ve
  always done it this way”,  “Management will never agree to allow us
  to have face to face release planning meetings”, “That not our job,
  we just code, I can’t worry about operations”, “why do we care about
  those other groups, we need to get our work done faster”

These questions have helped me to understand the factors that are important to success when deciding to let your own enterprise agile framework emerge (e.g. through trial and error).